# Alteração de domínio e servidor de site CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Desenvolvi um site em CakePHP e tive que mudar ele de domínio e servidor. Passei os arquivos para o servidor e configurei os arquivos de banco de dados na pasta `app/config/database.php`. Tudo certo, porém, ele nao ta puxando o css no `webroot` .. tem algum arquivo que indica dominio algo assim?

URL:

```
http://192.185.214.90/~imov2014
```

Comment: Você configurou a senha e o localhost? `$MySQLhostname = "localhost"; $MySQLusername = "root"; $MySQLpassword = "vertrigo"; $MySQLdb = "db";`

Comment: @user3443853 sim sim, configurei tudo, deve ser o mod_rewrite

Comment: Como você está chamando o CSS? As informações postadas não são suficientes para podermos diagnosticar o problema.

Comment: Sua hospedagem lhe permite acesso [tag:SSH]? Caso sim este artigo deve lhe ajudar http://jaydson.org/habilitar-mod_rewrite-no-apache/

Answer (score 1):

Provalvemente neste novo servidor o `mod_rewrite` do apache deve estar desativado.
O [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) precisa desse modulo para funcionar corretamente, só ativar que ficará ok.

Comment: como eu ativo ele?

Comment: é Localhost ou hospedagem paga?

Comment: eu alterei a questao veja